# Get list items only from a certain user

Tags: content-type

I would like to get all the items that were made by the user who's logged in on page_load.

I have something like that right now:

```
        SPWeb shpWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPUser currentUser = shpWeb.CurrentUser;
        SPQuery queryUserTimesheet = new SPQuery();
        queryUserTimesheet.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='CreatedBy' />" +
            "<Value Type='User'>" + currentUser.LoginName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
        SPListItemCollection items = shpWeb.Lists["TimesheetDB"].GetItems(queryUserTimesheet);
```

I'm using Content type list and i've added the sharepoint CreatedBy column to it. Eachtime an user make an entry it sets his name in this column. I would like to use this column to retrieve his data.

The thing is that this returns me 0 items, can't we do it on page load? Or what did i do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try Author as field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of CreatedBy, Use Author ,which is internal name of CreatedBy

```
"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='="Author' />" +
            "<Value Type='User'>" + currentUser.LoginName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

Comment: glad it worked for you

Comment: The user field in SharePoint for the user with presence type is populated by their SharePoint ID and not their name.  Glad this worked for you, and I am going to use it too :) but you use the ID to get the user name with presence.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you to use a tool like this: https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

and do some test by yourself to check what is wrong with your CAML query

> Use this program to help build and test SharePoint CAML Queries
>   (Collaborative Application Markup Language). Compatible with
>   SharePoint 2007, SharePoint 2010, SharePoint 2013 and Office365, in
>   one single convenient download containing two EXE files. Very similar
>   to U2U CAML Query Builder for SharePoint 2003 and SharePoint 2007.
>   This app uses the SharePoint Object Model and Web Services to connect
>   to a site using a URL. Gets all webs in a site, all lists in a web,
>   and all fields/columns in a list. Can export field information to CSV.
>   Also provides interface for building XML CAML Queries, with tools to
>   make it easier managing field names (using drag-drop and
>   copy-to-clipboard commands). Specify a query, view fields, view
>   attributes, and a row limit (0 to ignore) and run your query. Results
>   are output to a sortable grid and the data can be exported to CSV. The
>   grid shows the fields that are selected in the viewfields.

Comment: Can you describe a little further what you can do with this tool to solve OP's problem? Thanks!

Comment: Ok I doing this now

Answer (score 1):

I've always used this CAML query client-side and has always worked.

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Author'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value></Eq></Where>
```